# My Jacoco report is showing very little code coverage

Tags: java, scala, jacoco

I am trying to get an idea of how much code coverage I have with some unit tests in Scala and with the source code in Java(tests and code are in different packages). When I run the Jacoco report, it is showing only 4 percent code coverage.

When I go take a look at the report, it shows 0 percent for a lot of files that I have created tests for. What I suspect is that the unit tests are not being included in the report, maybe since all of the test class files are in the target/test-classes directory.
I have tried including the `includeTests` tag but that didn't have any effect.

Here is how the plugin looks like in the pom:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                        <!--<includes>
                            <include>**/test-classes/**</include>
                        </includes>-->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/dto/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/exceptions/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Right now I have commentted out the `include` tag becasue if I include it, the test compiles with 0 classes. How else can I can include the target/test-classes directory?

Sorry if this is a simple fix, I'm very new with unit testing and Jacoco. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal setup. It's a bit messy and I'm still working out some parts of it but it works for me. You could try this.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
     <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>0.8.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.20</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I have just tried this and I'm still getting the same thing as before...4% in the report